# How to use EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL in CMake?

Tags: cmake, build, linker

I'm trying to understand how to use `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` in CMakeList.txt. I've seen this example:

```
add_library(foo STATIC EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL "src/foo.cpp")
```

The only thing I understood from the documentation is that this property is a boolean value. But what does it do, and how do I use it in `add_executable()`, for example?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are not understanding what a make "target" is. When you build your code, you'll type "make all" or perhaps "make executableName" to build certain pieces of your software project. The portion being made is a make "target". That target name is defined when you call `add_executable()` (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html). 

By default, there is an `all` target, which will build everything. I believe the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` should exclude your library or executable from being built under the `all` target.

Comment: @Gemini specifically the CMake `ALL_BUILD` target. I use `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` a lot for my unit and functional tests. They are `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` by default, then added as a dependency of a `build_tests` target. Then, after generation, I can just do `cmake --build . --target build_tests` to only build tests, or `cmake --build .` to build the regular project.